# How to find the probability of a state from non-degenerate spectral decomposition

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, time-evolution, quantum-measurements

I have just begun learning the topics of time evolution in quantum mechanics, and I'm having trouble understanding how to calculate the probabilities of certain eigenvalues of an operator at a later time.

In my textbook, there is this example: For a quantum system with a Hamiltonian $H$ and operator $A$ with spectral decomposition given by
$$A = \sum_n a_n \lvert \psi_n \rangle \langle \psi_n \rvert \, .$$
The system is initially in the eigenstate $|\psi\rangle$ of $A$, with eigenvalue $a_n$. $H$ and $A$ do not commute. After time θ, the probability of obtaining the eigenvalue $a_n$ is given by 
$$w_{nn}(\theta) \approx 1 - (\Delta E)_n^2 \, \theta^2 \, .$$ 
I am completely clueless as to how this equation is derived. My attempt at deriving this would be to begin with $|\langle\psi_n|\psi_n\rangle|^2$ as this gives the probability of the system being at the same initial state, but I'm unsure if this approach is correct for time-evolving systems. I also noticed the θ in the equation, which leads me to think the time evolution operator $U$ is involved 
$$U = \exp(-i H t / \hbar) \, .$$
May someone provide an explanation or clue as to how measurements are calculated in this case?

Comment: Please use mathjax. Do not attach images of equations.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, unfortunately I know very little on how to use mathjax.

Comment: See the [help center](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation) and also just hit the "edit" button and see how I did it.

Comment: Thanks, will do!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, how we would find the probability of being in the same initial state (say $|\psi_n\rangle$) is as follows: 
$$P(|\psi_n\rangle, t) = |\langle\psi_n| \Psi \rangle|^2$$
where $|\Psi\rangle = e^{-i H t}|\psi_n \rangle$. Physically, how you should think about this expression is that I am finding the projection of my quantum state at time $t$ on my initial state which yields the probability of measuring my initial state. Now, we can do a simple calculation:
$$P(|\psi_n\rangle, t) = |\langle\psi_n|e^{-i H t}|\psi_n \rangle|^2 \approx |\langle\psi_n| 1- i H t - \frac{1}{2} H^2 t^2|\psi_n \rangle|^2 \approx | 1 - i \langle E \rangle - \frac{1}{2} \langle E^2\rangle t^2|^2 $$
$$\approx 1 - \langle E^2 \rangle t^2 - \langle E\rangle ^2 t^2 \approx 1 - \langle \Delta E^2\rangle t^2  $$
Note that this is a short time approximation where "short" is set by the characteristic energy scale.

Comment: Thank you very much! I understand how you approached this question, it is very similar to what I was thinking but I couldn't quite formalise it. Appreciated.